# I convert my Canon cr2 files to JPG in DPP, but when I copy them to SD card to be printed no images show?

Tags: raw

I recently set my Canon 7D Mark II to take pictures as .CR2 files (RAW). I then converted them in DPP 4 to JPG and copied them to an SD card to be printed by a third party. At the kiosk it states no images found. Even if the SD card is installed in the original camera or point and shoot camera, no images are found.
I can open the images in Photoshop or Windows Photo Viewer.
Previously I set my camera to take JPEG files and had no issues.

Comment: What folder are they saved at? Root (e.g. `F:/` )? Or `DCIM`?

Comment: Have you tried saving to another type of storage device such as a USB stick? (Or does the kiosk only accept SD cards?)

Comment: I did save the images to the SDXC root drive, I will also try a USB stick to see if that works. When I look at the image properties it state file type as JPEG image (.JPG). I will see if I can "export" plain JPEG instead of converting. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues:

- The kiosk doesn't recognize the card type or its file system (for instance is could not recognize SDXC cards)
- The kiosk only looks at the root of the card
- Your images have a file extension the kiosk doesn't recognize (`.jpeg` instead of `.jpg`, or even `.JPG` if it is case-sensitive)
- Your images are using a variation of the Jpeg standard that the kiosk doesn't recognize, the most frequent problem being images coded as "progressive" Jpeg (that has been part of the standard for more than 10 years...). Exporting plain Jpeg could be an option in DPP.